# Override a class attribute of the type of a generic type via a mixin so mypy won’t say it’s incompatible

Tags: generics, mypy, mixins, python-typing, class-attributes

I have a generic base class `A` that has an attribute containing the generic type `TK`.

```py
import typing


class K1:
    pass


TK = typing.TypeVar("TK", bound=K1)


class A(typing.Generic[TK]):
    k: type[TK]
```

Then I have a mixin `B` that should be applied on it in combination of a specific `TK` which is `K1`.

```py
class B:
    k = K1
```

Then I try to apply it to `A` like this:

```py
class AB(B, A[K1]):
    pass
```

The code works, but mypy complains:

> error: Definition of "k" in base class "B" is incompatible with definition in base class "A"

The issue won’t happen when directly inheriting it and doing the same assignment:

```py
class C(A[K1]):
    k = K1
```

Is there any way to make the mixin compatible with `A[K1]`? Notably the issue won’t happen when `A.k` isn’t annotated with the typevar, therefore I find it a bit odd.